# Perform update in multiple screens

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have three screens and each screen has a common column called DeptName. If i change the DeptName in one screen it will automatically update the Deptname name in other two screens. Is there any way to do that?

Please help me regarding this. I will be very thankful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that value should have been fetched from the database (so you wouldn't have that problem).

Anyway, if you have to do that, then "set value" **dynamic action** might help. If "current page" is P1 and another two pages are P2 and P3, then you'd

```
:P2_DEPTNAME := :P1_DEPTNAME;
:P3_DEPTNAME := :P1_DEPTNAME;
```